# ImageMagick gif creation is very slow (~40 seconds)

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to create a gif out of some Bitmap images and it takes a really long time for it to load. I followed the example on the library github page for this.

Here is my code:

```
    public void SaveAsGif(Stream stream, ICollection<Bitmap> images, float fps, bool loop)
    {
        ICollection<IMagickImage> magickImages = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<IMagickImage>();
        float exactDelay = 100 / fps;
        foreach (Bitmap bitmap in images)
        {
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage(bitmap);
            image.AnimationDelay = (int) exactDelay;
            if (!loop)
            {
                image.AnimationIterations = 1;
            }

            magickImages.Add(image);
        }

        using (MagickImageCollection collection = new MagickImageCollection(magickImages))
        {
            QuantizeSettings settings = new QuantizeSettings();
            settings.Colors = 256;
            collection.Quantize(settings);

            collection.Optimize();
            collection.Write(stream, MagickFormat.Gif);
        }
    }
```

I tested and the conversion of the images from bitmap to  MagickImages doesn't take very long, at most 5 seconds. And my images are about 4000x3000.
All the images have the same size. Writing to stream doesn't take long either. Any way to improve the timing?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy into a console app and reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: how many images are there. where is the time spent? In the loop?

Comment: ImageMagick uses a special quantization algorithm for processing gif that is somewhat slow because you have to reduce colors from millions to 256. It might be faster to specify your own color map and convert to 256 colors with -remap. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap

Comment: About 70 images, takes about 45 seconds to run this piece of code I gave you. For 20 images it took about 20 seconds. Which is still too much for what I want to use this.

Comment: I posted the entire method, just call this with a list of bitmaps, stream, loop and fps and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the slowness is in displaying the GIF, not generating it.  If that is the case, try resizing the image prior to calling the Add method.

e.g.:

```
image.Resize(400,300);
```

Comment: I dont want my gif to change its size. My problem is probably somewhere inbetween where I start using the MagickImageCollection. That's the piece of code that takes ~40 seconds to load

Comment: So a 24 bit BMP image may use about 36M of memory for each image.  This could be the bottleneck.  If you don't want to resize, you could try converting them to JPEG images first , which use much less memory - at least as an experiment to narrow the issue.